# How to find the namespace of a package with pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, python-wheel

I'm trying to write a custom package for python. It has the following folder structure:

```
E:\GITHUB\FUNCTIONSYNTHESIZER
│   .gitignore
│   LICENSE
│   README.md
│   setup.py
│
├───docs
│       docs.md
│       Example-6-Points.png
│
└────src
    │   function_synth.py
    │   __init__.py
    │
    └───__pycache__
```

Pip allows an install via the Folderpath of the setup.py. The setup.py follows the guidelines of [Python.org](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/) an most importantly works in another package with a different name:

```
from distutils.core import setup

def README():
    return open("README.md").read()

setup(name='function_synthesizer',
    version = '0.0.2',
    description = 'Generates a polynomial interpolation from a set up points',
    author = 'David J. Kowalk',
    author_email = '...',
    url = 'https://github.com/davidkowalk/FunctionSynthesizer',

    license = "MIT",
    keywords = "math interpolation polynomial calculus",

    long_description = README(),
    long_description_content_type='text/markdown',

    classifiers=[
        Calssifiers here
    ],

    package_dir = {'':'src'},

    python_requires = ">=3.6",
    install_requires=['numpy'],

    project_urls={
        'Bug Reports': '...',
        'Funding': '...',
        'Source': '...',
    }

)
```

The `__init__.py` imports the different functions of function_synth.

```
from function_synth import solve
from function_synth import to_str
from function_synth import calculate
```

The package gets installed by pip under the name "function_synthesizer" as defined by the setup.py but when I run `pip show function_synthesizer` I get

```
Name: function-synthesizer
Version: ...
```

This name violates the package name syntax and most importantly isn't defined anywhere. I cannot find any reason for that dash to be there, and it seems to replace the underscore defined by the `name` argument for some reason. But even when I remove the underscore and the resulting dash python is unable to import the packages under the following names:

- function_synthesizer
- function-synthesizer (syntax error at the dash)
- functionsynthesizer (after removing the dash)
- function_synth (file name)

Is there anyway of fetching the namespace from pip and how can I define that namespace in the setup.py?

Comment: I've exluded some info for readabillity, which I know have no effect.

Comment: Forget about the dist name in the metadata, it has no effect at runtime. Your package structure is wrong as you are not packaging any sources at all - check that by issuing `pip show -f function_synthesizer`, it probably won't list any python files.

Comment: Your `src` dir is declared to be a package (by placing an `__init__.py`). Is it intentional? If yes, the imports should be `from src.function_synth import ...` etc and you should include the `src` package in the setup script via `packages=['src']`. However, this is not what the `src` dir is for in the `src` layout. Or you want to install only `function_synth.py`, then use `py_modules` in the setup script to include it.

Comment: The file function_synth.py should be accessible when importing the package and I don't want there to be any modules since having only one module would be pretty pointless. Therefore I declared src to be a package and have the __init__.py import the functions of the file.

@hoefling is right though. Pip lists no Python files.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was fixed by adding a packages attribute:

```
packages = ["function_synthesizer"],
package_dir = {'function_synthesizer':'src'},
```

The `__init__.py` imports the functions then via

```
from function_synthesizer.function_synth import function_name
```